# How to show select box on focus and close after select?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-select

Could you please tell me how to show select box on focus of input field and close after select item from the drop down?
Here is my code

```
return (
      <div className="App">
        <Select
          value={selectedOption}
          closeMenuOnSelect={false}
          menuIsOpen={menuIsOpen}
          isMulti={true}
          className="select-item"
          classNamePrefix="select-item"
          onInputChange={() => this.setState({ menuIsOpen: true })}
          onChange={this.handleSelectedChange}
          options={options}
        />
      </div>
    );
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/5v41wrxw9n

using this plugin
https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to the link for updated code: https://codesandbox.io/s/mmjvp25z38

1. I used onFocus to show dropdown
2. Used on handleSelectedChange method and updated menuIsOpen prop via set state

Comment: Working fine but when you click outside the dropdown not hiding.

Comment: @HarishSoni please check the link now, I updated to fix that as well